# Item Bonus From Ancestral Geometry

Tags: pathfinder-2e, crafting

The second level tattoo Ancestral Geometry reads as follows:

> Geometric precision and perfect angles signify that an artist with exemplary knowledge of dwarven tattooing traditions created this body
> art. Your family's ancestral stories, recited throughout the tattooing
> process, bind your blood even tighter to theirs. During your daily
> preparations, you manifest a visitation by an ancestor—possibly via a
> dream, a vision, or a magical trinket left by your bedroll. Roll 2d20
> and record the highest result. Then roll 1d6 and note a type of saving
> throw: 1–2 Fortitude, 3–4 Reflex, and 5–6 Will.
>
> **In addition, until the next visitation, you gain a +1 item bonus to one Lore skill related to the ancestor, as determined by the GM.
> Usually, the ancestor provides a kind of knowledge they believe you'll
> need. For dwarven ancestors, the Lore skill is usually Architecture
> Lore, Engineering Lore, Genealogy Lore, Labor Lore, Mining Lore,
> Warfare Lore, or Lore about a dwarven deity.**
>
> Activate (Reaction) envision (fortune); Frequency once per day;
> Trigger You rolled a saving throw of the noted type; Effect Replace
> the roll with the d20 roll from your ancestor's visitation.

I'm unsure how to properly implement the second paragraph. My character happens to be a kobold trained in Kobold Lore. If the GM knows our party is likely to encounter kobolds during the upcoming day, I assume they would give that lore skill a temporary +1 item bonus until my next daily preparations. What about a lore skill that my character does not possess but would make thematic sense for my ancestry like Trap Lore or Dragon Lore? Do I temporarily gain that lore skill with a bonus of my intelligence modifier +1 with no proficiency? What other lore skills would be reasonable for a kobold? I assume anything listed in the ancestry entry in the APG?

> Typical kobold backgrounds include artisan, artist, criminal, hunter, miner, scout, and tinker from the Core Rulebook, plus bandit, cultist, scavenger, and servant from this book.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - are you the GM? Or the player? If you're the player, then you don't really get to choose the breadth of the Lore skills - that's entirely in your GM's hands.

Comment: Player, but just wanted to get a general sense of how narrow or broad this benefit could be during play. Also, this is our first PF campaign so I wanted to be able to provide some examples to the GM since I don't necessarily expect him to have a deep understanding of each ancestry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## You Don't Get Free Proficiency

The [Ancestral Geometry tattoo](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2202) does give you a (GM-determined) variable +1 to a Lore skill, but never mentions that it gives you any proficiency. So if you are untrained in the Lore skill, you would use: untrained proficiency plus your Intelligence modifier plus any bonuses (minus any penalties). If you have 14 Intelligence, and a +1 item bonus to Lore (Sewers), but were untrained, you'd simply have a +3 to Lore (Sewers) checks.

### How To Make This Better

Since there are an infinite amount of Lore skills, you have a few options to try making this better:

- [Untrained Improvisation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=861) - this will provide some scaling to those Lore skills you don't have.
- [Additional Lore](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=750) - it's likely the GM will be providing a common set of Lore skill bonuses, and grabbing this for a few of them can help keep those relevant.
- Class abilities like [Access Lore](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=741) - this one provides a flexible Lore proficiency.

## Some recommended Lores

You touched on a good place to find relevant Lore skills for kobolds. Here are seven recommendations to align with the 7 ones provided for dwarves - by no means is any GM restricted to this list, nor is it exhaustive. They are all from the Common [Lore](https://2e.aonprd.com/Skills.aspx?ID=8) Subcategories though, and so should both be fair and potentially come up in pre-written adventures.

- Kobold Lore
- Dragon Lore
- Specific Dragon Category Lore (e.g. Chromatic, Metallic, Imperial)
- Dahak Lore (assuming Golarion)
- Apsu Lore (assuming Golarion)
- Terrain Lore (probably things like Caves and Swamps, but maybe even Sewers)
- Absalom Lore (or other relevant city with a kobold population)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and also providing some avenues for getting the most out of the lore skills. Cheers!

Comment: I still find it kind of odd that Untrained Improvisation gives you Lore (all). I don't think it's wrong, but I don't think I'd allow it in my home games. Although I might make an exception for situations like this one

Comment: @Ifusaso it is weird, but it's a weird feat narratively in general... at level 20 you're 8 Int Barbarian knows more about arcana than a 7th level Wizard who is a master in it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯